# Is there a database which holds some kind of student email format of different universities in US?

Tags: database

The Norwegian University of Science and Technology has the email format that looks like this: @stud.ntnu.no, other schools have different format for their student email addresses. Is there a database out there that holds some record of student email address formats of different universities and colleges in US?

I will use it to confirm that a student is a student by sending a confirmation email to the student email address. But before I can send the confirmation email I need to check that the email format is a valid student email format.

Comment: The [help/on-topic] says very clearly *Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow*.

Comment: In the United States and for many foreign counties, you can use `.edu` or `.ed.??` or `.ac.??` where `??` is the country domain suffix.